# Silverlight UserControl Parent is Always Null in its constructor. Any recommendations?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a user control that I have set as the Source of a Silverlight Frame.  When I get the Parent of the user control in it's constructor, it returns Null.   Is there an event of UserControl that is called after the control is loaded in the frame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about the [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event. If I understand your question correctly the Loaded event should be what you need to attach a handler for. That event fires after the object has been constructed, *and added to the visual tree*. So at that point it should have it's parent references set correctly.

Comment: i have to set some properties of the user control that is used in the frame. i dont want to pass in query string values.  can i not create the class object of the user control, set its properties and set as frame's source?